# Downloading High Sierra to a Mojave-capable iMac

Tags: high-sierra

I have a late 2014 iMac that is running Yosemite and is ccompatible with Mojave. But I want to upgrade the OS to High Sierra, not Mojave.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're in the US, go to [this link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/macos-high-sierra/id1246284741?mt=12).

Note: Links to all macOS downloads from Leopard to Mojave are listed [on this page at Krypted.com](http://krypted.com/mac-os-x/download-older-versions-of-macos-and-mac-os-x/).

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do something similar recently, and I found the downloaded High Sierra I had saved was corrupt in some way, and I re-downloaded via the App Store…which gave me a stub installer (about 20MB) rather than the full 5.7GB version.

The way I found to force the full download from Apple was to use [High Sierra Patcher Tool](http://dosdude1.com/highsierra/) from dosdude1.com -- download it, unzip the archive, run the app inside (you will likely need to right-click -> open as the developer is not recognised). Ignore all the stuff about patching your system, clear any dialogs about your system already being supported (if they appear and choose `Tools` -> `Download macOS High Sierra…`:

[image: Download High Sierra]

The patcher app will ask you for confirmation:

[image: Download High Sierra confirmation]

Select `Yes` and it will start downloading the full installer:

[image]

At the end of this process, you'll have a working self-contained High Sierra installer. The patcher will ask if you want to make a patched USB installer -- answer `Not now` to this:

[image]

Locate the download in your chosen folder, and you should have a 5.7GB portable installer:

[image]

After you've installed High Sierra, you can change the macOS update settings to defer (possibly indefinitely, to be confirmed) the Mojave installer auto-downloading using `System Preferences` -> `App Store` -> uncheck `Install macOS updates`:

[image]

You can opt-in to any updates when you're ready.